# Get local variable value from annotated method in aspectJ

Tags: java, methods, aop, aspectj, local-variables

I am using java **custom annotation** with aspectJ

**CUSTOM ANNOTATION**

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TrxLogger {

String author() default "Shahid Ghafoor";
String comments() default "I am Fan of JAVA";
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
public class Service {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@TrxLogger
public String sayHello(String fn, String ln) {

    this.name=fn;

     String localVariable="Before System.out.println";

    System.out.println("Welcome!" + fn + " " + ln);

    return "The Transaction return Value";
}

}
```

**ASPECT**

```
@Around(value="pcSample(tl)", argNames="tl")
public Object runMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, TrxLogger tl) throws Throwable {

 return null;
}
```

is it possible to get local variable value(`String localVariable="Before System.out.println";`) of sayHello() Method in aspect ?

Answer (score 3):

No, a local variable is just that, local. You cannot dig into the method to access it. The body of a method is not accessible through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

when method sayHello execute that time only lovalVariable have value. otherwise it's not known by anybody.

Comment: can we not find after pjp.proceed() ?